# AWS Lambda Function - Doing writes to Dynamo Db

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

My architecture is something like as:-

SNS -> AWS Lambda -> Dynamo Db

So, SNS is publishing messages to which AWS Lambda function is the subscriber and then AWS Lambda pushes the data into Dynamo Db.

So, here is it a good idea to do writes to Dynamo Db on every message I receive? Will it make the AWS Lambda slow or that would be okay? Or is there anyway I can collect the messages from Lambda and then push them in a batch to Dynamo Db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't collect multiple messages in Lambda and push them in a batch. Once your Lambda invocation is over the Lambda execution environment may be destroyed. You have to write your output somewhere outside of the Lambda environment before you exit the Lambda invocation.

Comment: But what about if I am writing single message every time to dynamo db from AWS Lambda? Will it not be a good idea? Any suggestions.

Comment: You have to make sure the configured throughput of your DynamoDB table can handle the amount of updates the Lambda function will generate.

Comment: Actually, one more question, if you could answer. I am not able to post more question as of today as I have exceeded the limit of 6/day in StackOverflow. My question is a continuation of above, i.e. can I push the data from Lambda to Kinesis and from Kinesis, do the batch write to DynamoDb. Not sure, if Kinesis is for that purpose or not?